# Ad failed to load with error code 0(internal Error) - Huawei Ads Implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ads

I m getting the above error continuously in demo Application. I have HMS core Version 5.0.0.329(Initial Version). My internet connection is stable. I have created  test application on app gallery that has been approved but still same error. No luck yet.

> *Note: This Error only occurs on Huawei Device Y6p - Model- MED-LX9 -Android Version -10.
> Ads Showing on Samsung S7 - Android Version - 7.0

Following is the code for my test application. I m using Android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

> Module.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
}

android {
compileSdk 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.huaweitestads"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//Huawei Dependency
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.45.308'
//implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads:3.4.45.308'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-identifier:3.4.34.301'
}
```

> Project.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
}
dependencies {
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> setting.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
google()
jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
}
}
rootProject.name = "HuaweiTestAds"
include ':app'
```

> MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val adListener: AdListener = object : AdListener(){
override fun onAdClosed() {
showToast("Ad closed")
}

    override fun onAdFailed(p0: Int) {
        showToast(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "Ad failed to load with error code %d.", p0))
    }

    override fun onAdLeave() {
        showToast("Ad Leave")
    }

    override fun onAdOpened() {
        showToast(String.format("Ad opened "))
    }

    override fun onAdLoaded() {
        showToast("Ad loaded.")
    }

    override fun onAdClicked() {
        showToast("Ad clicked")
    }

    override fun onAdImpression() {
        showToast("Ad Impression")
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //initialize the Huawei Ads
    HwAds.init(this)

    val bannerView: BannerView? = findViewById(R.id.hw_banner_view)
    bannerView!!.adListener = adListener
    bannerView.setBannerRefresh(30)
    val adParam = AdParam.Builder().build()
    bannerView.loadAd(adParam)
}
private fun showToast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
}
```

> activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:hwads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cl_root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello "
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.huawei.hms.ads.banner.BannerView
    android:id="@+id/hw_banner_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    hwads:adId="testw6vs28auh3"
    hwads:bannerSize="BANNER_SIZE_320_50" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> logCat Exception:
> 2021-08-27 15:11:48.642 20928-20928/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to
> instantiate appComponentFactory
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip
> file
> "/data/app/com.huawei.appmarket-KidEWN7eyzOMAnU7Zs1jjg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.huawei.appmarket-KidEWN7eyzOMAnU7Zs1jjg==/lib/arm,
> /data/app/com.huawei.appmarket-KidEWN7eyzOMAnU7Zs1jjg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
> /system/lib, /hw_product/lib, /system/product/lib]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:270)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:922)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1044)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1293)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2610)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2598)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7222)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:308)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2295)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)

Exception 2:

> 2021-08-27 15:11:31.275 20725-20779/? E/ServiceRegistrarParser: get
> ServiceDiscovery
> exception.ComponentInfo{com.huawei.hms.agclink/com.huawei.agconnect.core.ServiceDiscovery}
> 2021-08-27 15:11:31.298 17647-18622/? E/fwkit_kitProviderDispatcher:
> [E/fwkit/fwkit_kitProviderDispatcher 17647:4417
> StubContentProvider.java:153] NameNotFoundException
> android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
> at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:201)
> at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:170)
> at com.huawei.hms.fwkit.kams.provideragent.a.a(KitProviderDispatcher.java:387)
> at com.huawei.hms.fwkit.kams.provideragent.a.a(KitProviderDispatcher.java:320)
> at com.huawei.hms.fwkit.kams.provideragent.StubContentProvider.getType(StubContentProvider.java:153)
> at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.getType(ContentProvider.java:295)
> at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:140)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1028)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1001)

Exception 3:

> 2021-08-27 15:12:07.512 4661-4736/? E/PushLog110102300:
> [SocketRead_15:10:54-308]read socket occurs
> Exception: com.huawei.android.pushagent.datatype.exception.PushException
> r*a* n*r*a* E*i*
> ee.ck(Unknown Source:101)
> ee.run(Unknown Source:40)

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: hi @shirley, can you please share your thoughts about it. Thanks

Comment: hi@waheed shah, sorry for the late reply, i just posted my answer below. pls let me know   If there are any questions.

Comment: hi @shirley, thanks for your response I have already added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in menifest but downgraded the target SDK version wont help to remove the error. No success :(

Comment: @waheedshah Off-topic, but do you use Huawei ads in your apps that published on Google Play?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI No! not yet. I m just doing it for huwaei App gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei Y6p has encountered the same problem before on this device. You can check there is a SIM card.

After the SIM is inserted, the country code of the SIM card will be read.
Rules for obtaining the country code: country code of the place of shipment> country code of the sim card> country set by the mobile phone.

Comment: What if! I dont want to add a sim in the testing device? Is there some other solutions you can share? Have you ever tried this on Huawei Y6p?

Comment: I don't have a Huawei Y6p device, I haven't tried it before. We want those who encounter this kind of problem on the Huawei Y6p device to insert a sim card so that they can get results.

Comment: After adding the sim in the Huawei Y6p. Ads are going to show up! @efnan can you please share how do you know about it? What particular devices shows this kinda behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

As [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-integrating-sdk-0000001050066913#section19869145195218) mentioned, To allow HTTP and HTTPS network requests on devices with targetSdkVersion 28 or later, pls configure the following information in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    >
    ...
</application>
```

Then change targetSdk **30** in Gradle to **29**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

recommended versions are as in the [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-dev-process-0000001050064964)

```
compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: Though it is recommended version but I believe you can use the above versions too.

Comment: Huawei Y6p has encountered the same problem before on this device. You can check there is a SIM card.

After the SIM is inserted, the country code of the SIM card will be read. Rules for obtaining the country code: country code of the place of shipment> country code of the sim card> country set by the mobile phone.